# How to show swagger/ui/index page in .Net Framework 4.7 project which is deployed in IIS with .com

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a web api project which is running in .NET Framework 4.7. I have added the Reference Swashbuckle.Core for showing the swagger ui. I have updated the .csproj also to add the documentation .xml file.  It is working in my development machine when I run my application using the url http://localhost:55677/swagger/ui/index. But when i publish the application using visual studio, it is showing as "404 - File or directory not found".  It might be because the UI page Swaggerui is not available in the published bin folder.  The published url looks like "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.com".  But after loading i give like "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.com/swagger/ui/index" to show the swagger ui.  But it is showing the 404 error.  I am not using any .net core project. Just .net framework only.

Someone please help me on this.

After looked into several sites, i have added these code part in the SwaggerConfig.cs file.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "App Name");
                    // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
                   var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory + "bin\\", xmlFile);
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);                        
                    c.ApiKey(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("apikey"))
                    .Description("API Key Authentication")
                    .Name("key-name")
                    .In("header");
                    c.RootUrl(req =>
                        req.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) +
                        req.GetRequestContext().VirtualPathRoot.TrimEnd('/'));
                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {
                    c.EnableApiKeySupport("key-name", "header");
                });
```

RootUrl is the one i found from a site to redirect to SwaggerUI page. But it is not working.

Comment: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1190 have you out the solutions given on the link?

Comment: Since i am not using any .net core application, the SwaggerEndpoint keyword is not available. RoutePrefix keyword also is not available.

Comment: Hi, did you ever get this working?

Comment: Hey OP were you able to find a solution for this, i get 404 when hosted in IIS plain web api application and not .net core